# how can i write custom directive in angulargs ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

i have a requirement of writing a custom directive in angular ui-grid , i want to call a function when a user press "enter" on some particular column ,but i am not allowed to write a custom directive on the column , how can i achieve this functionality ????

i have shared the code below where i have written a directive "enter" this directive i want to include at the column "company" i hope i am clear with the question.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.rowEdit', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', '$interval', function ($scope, $http, $q, $interval) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true
  };

  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'firstname', enableCellEdit: true },
    { name: 'lastname', displayName: 'Name (editable)' },
    { name: 'company',},
    { name: 'employed', displayName: 'employe'},
 
  ];

  $scope.saveRow = function( rowEntity ) {
    // create a fake promise - normally you'd use the promise returned by $http or $resource
    var promise = $q.defer();
    $scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setSavePromise( $scope.gridApi.grid, rowEntity, promise.promise );
   
    // fake a delay of 3 seconds whilst the save occurs, return error if gender is "male"
    $interval( function() {
      if (rowEntity.lastname === 'irfan' ){
        promise.reject();
      } else {
        promise.resolve();
      }
    }, 3000, 1);
  }; 
  $scope.addData = function() {
     var n = $scope.gridOptions.data.length + 1;
     $scope.gridOptions.data.push({
                 "firstName":"",
                 "lastName": "",
                 "company": "",
                 "employed": true
               });
   };

  $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
    //set gridApi on scope
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope, $scope.saveRow);
  };

  var data1 = [
               {
                 "firstName": "Cox",
                 "lastName": "Carney",
                 "company": "Enormo",
                 "employed": true
               },
               {
                 "firstName": "Lorraine",
                 "lastName": "Wise",
                 "company": "Comveyer",
                 "employed": false
               },
               {
                 "firstName": "Nancy",
                 "lastName": "Waters",
                 "company": "Fuelton",
                 "employed": false
               },
               {
                 "firstName": "Misty",
                 "lastName": "Oneill",
                 "company": "Letpro",
                 "employed": false
               }
             ];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: data1
    };
}]);
app.directive("enter", function () {
   return function (scope, element, attrs) {
     element.bind("click", function () {
       scope.addData();
     })
   }})
```

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
.grid {
  width: 950px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<button type="button" id="addData" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addData()">Add ROW</button>
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-cellNav class="grid"></div>
</div>

  <script src="workinggrid2.js"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Before I ask what your directive has to do with pressing ENTER (It seems to be designed for the click event) and if it works, just tell me where you are using it. Shouldn't this be somewhere in a cellTemplate or what do you mean with "press "enter" on some particular column"?

Comment: i have not used the directive somewhere yet, and that is my question how to use the directive on some particular column to achieve some task, the above written "enter" directive is just an example or a dummy directive u can say

Comment: what basically i want to achieve is when user press "enter" on the last column of the row(in a editable mode), it should add a new row  The "addData()" function should be called on the press of "enter" in the last column of the row , which currently i am calling with "add row" button. hope i am clear now

Comment: Too bad I can't edit your code snippet. Can you create a Plunker instead?

Comment: here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/sbTJmuAmsgfqoYZRXb8l?p=preview